# Show connected (up) interfaces on cisco devices

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, cli

Is there any way to show a total count of interfaces that are in status "up" on a cisco router?

The purpose is to let a script go through all routers and show a summarization count of "up" interfaces.

Comment: ex: cisco 881, v12.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can show all interfaces that are up by:

```
show interfaces status | include connected
```

Then your script can count them.

The `show interfaces status` cli command shows you all interfaces. The interfaces that are "up" are in the `connected` state. The `| include connected` shows only the lines of the output that contain the word "connected".

[Newer Cisco IOS contain a `count` parameter](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/configuration/guide/15_1s/cf_15_1s_book/feat_show_cmd_redrct.html) that can count lines which match a regex. This is not available on all IOS versions.

Comment: The problem is here that I have a script that already does the batch executing on multiple routers so I need the count in one line as a response. Is this possible?

Comment: After reading the Cisco documentation, there is a | count option in newer IOS (15.x) but it's only in the newer IOS versions so you can't be sure if it's available.

Comment: idd, the count option did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use these commands:

sh ip int bri | include up
sh int des | include up

Comment: This is a bit prone to false positives, since any port with 'up' in the description will always match regardless of its state.

Comment: Yeah, but it does show line protocol status, which is beneficial in troubleshooting layer 1 and 2 interface issues.

Comment: To get rid of false positives use: show ip int br | i up.*up